# Deserialize IRestResponse and write out to console, C#

Tags: c#, json, api, restsharp, json-deserialization

I'm using CalorieNinjas API to build a simple console app in C#.
User enters an ingredient and the API returns various nutrition values in JSON format: 
[JSON output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfgwP.png) 
The problem on my side is, that I don't know exactly how to deserialize the JSON output to some format like array, List or Dictionary and how to write the list/dictionary values to console.
What I have right now is a class which represents the outputed JSON data:

```
public class Nutrition
    {
        public double sugar_g { get; set; }
        public double fiber_g { get; set; }
        public int serving_size_g { get; set; }
        public int sodium_mg { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int potassium_mg { get; set; }
        public int fat_saturated_g { get; set; }
        public double fat_total_g { get; set; }
        public double calories { get; set; }
        public int cholesterol_mg { get; set; }
        public double protein_g { get; set; }
        public double carbohydrates_total_g { get; set; }
    }
```

and then a List on class level:

```
public List<Nutrition> NutritionList { get; set; }
```

What I have right now is:

```
        IRestResponse<Nutrition> response = client.Execute<Nutrition>(request);
        JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
        
        //foreach(var item in NutritionList)
        //{
        //  Console.WriteLine(item...)
        //}
        Console.ReadKey();
```

It's probably a simple solution, but I just can't figure it out. I am thankful for any help :)

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is

`List<Nutrition> nutritionList= client.Execute<List<Nutrition>>(request).Data;`